# C# How to display all external console app message in a rich text box

Tags: c#, console-application, richtextbox, messaging

How to read all the messages sent from an external console app and display in rich text box

I have a C# windows forms project that runs an external console application.
I have the code below that displays messages from the app in a rich text box but it is not displaying all the information or error messages.
I have found lots of examples that state this can be done but it is displayed in the console and I have not been able to find a way to convert this to display in a rich text box.

Is it possible to convert the code below to display all messages and errors?

```
string strParameters;
strParameters = "-p " + CmboDeviceList.Text;
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.FileName = TxtPathToExtApp.Text;
startInfo.Arguments = strParameters;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();                        
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
RtxtExtAppOutput.Text = output;
process.WaitForExit();
```

Update:
Thanks to a pointer from Lex Li I have now resolved this.

```
string strParameters;
strParameters = "-p " + CmboDeviceList.Text;
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.FileName = TxtPathToExtApp.Text;
startInfo.Arguments = strParameters;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();                        
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() + process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
RtxtExtAppOutput.Text = output;
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: What is "all the information or error messages", please elaborate on it. Because `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` is what you could read.

Comment: It is not displaying all messages or error, warnings or info messages. This one app I am running there should be about 8 lines displayed (as there is when run from the command prompt). I am seeing only one or two lines.Also it displays when the app is closed. I was hoping maybe for live data. I did find one link that suggested writing to a test file and then displaying that, but I cannot find it now. I think it may have been using a completely different method though..

Comment: Why do you only redirect stdout? stderr should also be redirected in case the console app writes to that.

Comment: Thanks Lex. Good pointer. it is now displaying the same as the command prompt does.